# Cassandra2.0.1 fail to restart when private ip is changed on ec2 with ebs

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, cluster-computing, restart

I use a cassandra cluster of 3 EC2 instance nodes on AWS.

Each node mount a EBS volume to the path(/usr/lib/cassandra/), so data of cassandra is stored in EBS volume.

All nodes have a dns to point the private ip of themselves. And all cassandra configure files use the DNS instead of the private ip.

My question is that: when an node is teminated, and i will lanuch another cassandra, and mount the EBS to the newly-launched instance, so the data will not be losted. But when starting cassandra service, cassandra service will fail. And the log is as bellow:

I don't know why it will use ip of other nodes ?

```
 INFO 12:47:36,364 Writing Memtable-schema_keyspaces@1358300025(251/2510 serialized/live bytes, 8 ops)
 INFO 12:47:36,367 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columns@1982787565(91991/919910 serialized/live bytes, 2375 ops)
 INFO 12:47:36,367 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@59370809(38866/388660 serialized/live bytes, 1052 ops)
 INFO 12:47:36,385 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_keyspaces/system-schema_keyspaces-jb-10-Data.db (214 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1382719654978, position=289)
 INFO 12:47:36,391 Writing Memtable-schema_columns@1982787565(91991/919910 serialized/live bytes, 2375 ops)
 INFO 12:47:36,627 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columns/system-schema_columns-jb-24-Data.db (19358 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1382719654978, position=289)
 INFO 12:47:36,628 Writing Memtable-schema_columnfamilies@59370809(38866/388660 serialized/live bytes, 1052 ops)
 INFO 12:47:36,660 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-24-Data.db (8750 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1382719654978, position=289)
 INFO 12:47:36,661 Log replay complete, 64 replayed mutations
 INFO 12:47:36,746 Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-23-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-22-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-24-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-21-Data.db')]
 INFO 12:47:37,584 Compacted 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/schema_columnfamilies/system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-25,].  34,990 bytes to 8,759 (~25% of original) in 809ms = 0.010325MB/s.  16 total rows, 4 unique.  Row merge counts were {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:4, }
 INFO 12:47:38,411 Cassandra version: 2.0.1
 INFO 12:47:38,412 Thrift API version: 19.37.0
 INFO 12:47:38,425 CQL supported versions: 2.0.0,3.1.1 (default: 3.1.1)
 INFO 12:47:38,485 Loading persisted ring state
ERROR 12:47:38,537 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown host /172.31.9.175 with no default configured
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.PropertyFileSnitch.getEndpointInfo(PropertyFileSnitch.java:90)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.PropertyFileSnitch.getDatacenter(PropertyFileSnitch.java:113)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch.getDatacenter(DynamicEndpointSnitch.java:127)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata$Topology.addEndpoint(TokenMetadata.java:1049)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata.updateNormalTokens(TokenMetadata.java:187)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata.updateNormalTokens(TokenMetadata.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:470)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:428)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:343)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:442)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:485)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown host /172.31.9.175 with no default configured
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.PropertyFileSnitch.getEndpointInfo(PropertyFileSnitch.java:90)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.PropertyFileSnitch.getDatacenter(PropertyFileSnitch.java:113)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch.getDatacenter(DynamicEndpointSnitch.java:127)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata$Topology.addEndpoint(TokenMetadata.java:1049)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata.updateNormalTokens(TokenMetadata.java:187)
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata.updateNormalTokens(TokenMetadata.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:470)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:428)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:343)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:442)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:485)
Exception encountered during startup: Unknown host /172.31.9.175 with no default configured
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but in your cassandra.yaml, you may want to look at the seeds variable, it probably is incorrectly referencing an old IP.  Another way around this is to use some of the floating IPs in AWS. That way if you spin up a new machine you point the floating IPs to it, and the configuration wouldn't have to change the IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have configured Default for unknown nodes in your snitch property file.

```
default =<Any of your DC name>:RAC1
```

After making the changes restart, hope this will help.